# 'class' type redefinition, already included ifndef/define/endif

Tags: c++

New to c++ and confused. I've looked up dozens of similar issues and every solution is to add `#pragma once` or `#ifndef/#define/#endif`, however it doesn't seem to be the case for me. I have a tic tac toe board source file *tttBoard.cpp*, as seen below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tttBoard.h"
#include <string>

class tttBoard {

    enum sVal {sEmp,sX,sO};
    sVal gBoard[3][3];
    bool isX;

    tttBoard::tttBoard() {
    }

    void Draw() {
    }

    void Move(int x, int y) {
    }

    char* getValue(int x, int y) {}

};
```

and the respective header file, *tttBoard.h*:

```
#ifndef tttBoard_h
#define tttBoard_h

class tttBoard {
    public:
        tttBoard();
        void            Draw();
        void            Move(int x, int y);
        char*           getValue(int x, int y);
    private:
        enum sVal {
        sEmp,
        sX,
        sO
        };

        sVal            gBoard[3][3];
        bool            isX;
};

#endif
```

However when compiling I come across the following errors:

```
tttboard.cpp(5): error C2011: 'tttBoard' : 'class' type redefinition
tttboard.h(4) : see declaration of 'tttBoard'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the class, you don't redefine it. Try as follows in your `.cpp` file.

```
#include "tttBoard.h"

tttBoard::tttBoard() {
}

void tttBoard::Draw() {
}

void tttBoard::Move(int x, int y) {
}

char* tttBoard::getValue(int x, int y) {}
```

You also don't need to redeclare your `enum sVal`, or any of the `tttBoard` member variables. They should be available from your original declaration in your header file. :-)

Also, make sure `getValue` is implemented to actually return something. You will be unable to compile until you finish implementing these functions.

Read more on C++ classes [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).

Comment: Thanks! I really should have read more into C++ before diving head first but it's needed for a school assignment and wasn't given much heads up. I think I understand header file a little better now.

Comment: @Chris no problem! It's good to ask questions so you may learn.

Comment: Don't be scared of carefully reading your error messages. =)  Those two messages told you exactly what you were doing wrong, where you were doing it, and where the original definition was.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing the definition of the class both in the header and the implementation file. In the .cpp just include the header.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are attempting to define the class methods and end up **re-declaring** the class itself in the .cpp file.
Definitions of the function should be as following in the .cpp file:

```
tttBoard::tttBoard() {
}

void tttBoard::Draw() {
}

void tttBoard::Move(int x, int y) {
}

char* tttBoard::getValue(int x, int y) { return ...; }
```

Note that, you don't have to again mention the non-static data members and enums etc. in the .cpp file.
Declaration and definitions can be in separate sections only for functions.